# Identify BLE device that is notifying

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have multiple BLE devices connected each 'notifying' when their battery state changes.

How can Identify which BLE is notifying when data is read after being notified of a change in state?

```
// Instance method to get the battery state
- (void) getBattery:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
{
    //----------------
    NSLog(@"getBattery");
    //----------------
    {
        // Get the Battery Data
        NSLog(@"Battery Level is : %@ (HEX)" , characteristic.value);
    }
}
```

This is the code reading the data when notified to...

Thanks for your answer, but it appears I'm only receiving data from the last service setup to notify from. Here is the calling code for Notify...

Hi, That's great. I can identify the device notifying when data has changed.

But, it appears that my code is only notifying and collecting data from the last characteristic identified.

Here is the calling code:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral    didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{

// Retrieve the characteristic value for battery
if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SR1_DEVICE_BATTERY_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID]])    {
[self getBattery:characteristic];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a peripheral sends a notification that a value has changed, the `CBPeripheralDelegate` method [`didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBPeripheralDelegate/peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:) is invoked.  This method includes a reference to the `CBPeripheral`. You don't show how you get from this method to your `getBattery` method, but you need pass the peripheral when you do.

You can also reference the peripheral property of the service property of the `CBCharacteristic` -

```
 CBPeripheral *p=characteristic.service.peripheral;
```